# Google Sheets: Re-Sort range after Row is auto moved by script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pml-Q2cFhHbvXC74BKaVr7hpVoAhEG-aBi3GMBOl_Og/edit#gid=0) code that will move an entire row of data from one sheet to another within the same workbook based on Checkbox value:

```
function onEdit(e){

  // WORKING
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart != 3) return;
  let dest;
  if (src.getName() == "New")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
  else if (src.getName() == "Complete")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("New");  
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,3).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,3));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);

  
  // NOT WORKING
  src.getRange("A2:Z").sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]);
  dest.getRange("A2:Z").sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]);

}
```

In addition, after the moving has taken place, I am trying to get **both** the sheets to "re-sort". I have tried with a filer on the current column, but I than have to manually re-filter after the moving. "Not working" = no sorting is taking place after the rows are moved!

**How can both sheets be re-sorted after the rows has been triggered to move?**

Answer (score 0):

Add (assuming that your script gives the result you expect):

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

before sorting
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush